# How do I create a csv file with 100,000 random pairs in python?

Tags: python, csv, random

I need to create a `csv` file with 100,000 random pairs.

So far I have:

```
import random

randfile = open("Random.csv", "w" )
pairs = []
for i in range(100000):
    line1 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    line2 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    pair = line1, line2
    pairs.append(pair)

randfile.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track actually. You can use `csv.writer` to easily write to a csv file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import random
>>> randfile = open("Random.csv", "w")
>>> writer = csv.writer(randfile, delimiter=",")
>>> for i in range(100000):
...     pair = random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)
...     writer.writerow(pair)
...
>>> randfile.close()
```

You don't need to have `pairs` and `pairs.append(pair)`, you can throw them away your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

with open("Random.csv", "w" ) as outf:
    outfile = csv.writer(outf)
    for i in range(100000):
        num1 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        num2 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        row = (num1,num2)
        outfile.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, but you did not write anything to your file you just opened and closed it.

Just add this line before closing and it will work fine:

```
randfile.write('\n'.join('%d,%d' % (a,b) for a, b in pairs))
```